# Raspberry Pi Captured image quality in python vs raspistill

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm using my raspberry pi to detect when my cats are on the table, and I'm having a bit of trouble with a couple of the image capture pieces.  Here's the relevant code I'm running:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import subprocess

#method 1
with PiCamera() as camera:
    capImg = PiRGBArray(camera)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    camera.capture(capImg,format = 'bgr')
    image = capImg.array
    cv2.imwrite('image4.bmp',image)

#method 2
callString = 'raspistill -n -w %s -h %s -o /home/pi/python/catcam/image5.bmp --timeout 0' % (640,480)
subprocess.call(callString, shell = True)
```

Is there a way to keep raspistill images in memory or do something like camera.capture_continuous?  Comparing the quality of the picamera image:

[image]

the colors are much better with raspistill:

[image]

I'd like to capture an image every few seconds, but don't want to be writing to disk for every single image or I'll burn my memory card out quite quickly. Also, raspistill is quite slow.

Any pointers on how to capture better quality images at a constant rate would be much appreciated!

**EDIT** Thanks to Mark below, I have edited post to current issue at hand.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/api_camera.html) you need to call `camera.close()` when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks - that helps!  I've edited above, but the crux of the issue remains - differing qualities between the two image capture methods.

Comment: I think the quality looks great in both. The only issue looks like brightness or contrast... Maybe a higher iso setting or changing the auto white balance AWB to something other than auto. There's a few basic settings you can play with to see if you can get the same brightness. Described in readme at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/python/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply - given that the raspistill is providing a much better "auto" version, I'm still curious if there is a way to keep that in memory and   take images quickly/capture a movie. The picamera version tends to oscillate between the blue-ish tint shown above and and orange tint very easily, so correcting is more work than I'd like to do.

Comment: Perhaps increasing the pre-capture delay might help? In my own tests it seems 0.3s is needed for the AGC to adjust the exposure, but then that might be different from camera to camera (I use the [Waveshare "IR-Cut" camera](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RPi_IR-CUT_Camera)). I also have no idea how raspistill deals with this, so I may well be talking nonsense here!

Comment: @JosephPalermo Not sure how anyone can answer. Your contact links in your profile don't work. It is unclear what actual code you want to run. What quality issue you have. Which camera you use. What frame rate or resolution you need.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [How to make a temporary file in RAM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188540/468799)

You should be able to allocate some space in RAM directly as a user (but you need root permissions).

Creating a new mount partition of size 500 MB:

```
# this is bash, not python
mount -t tmpfs -o size=500m tmpfs /mountpoint
```

And utilize it as any other space you have

```
# this too
raspistill -n -w %s -h %s -o /mountpoint/image5.bmp --timeout 0
```

Comment: Why not just write on `/tmp` which is already a `tmpfs` based filesystem, already mounted for you and not requiring root?

Comment: the OP on linked question claims, that `/tmp` is not in RAM, so that's why.

Comment: It seems to be on `tmpfs` if you run `mount` and check... `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noatime)`

Comment: In that case, OP can check to make sure this is true for them as well, and then just use that instead (so no need to mount it themselves) @MarkSetchell

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Thanks! Is there any advantage to mounting your own partition in tmpfs?

For others, FYI that any partition mounted to tmpfs is stored in RAM.

By running ```mount | grep -i tmpfs``` you can find the partitions that live on RAM. You can also confirm that a given partition, (i.e. '/dev/shm') lives on RAM by running ```df -hT /dev/shm```. Once pick a partition (i.e. '/dev/shm') you can simply run ```raspistill -o /dev/shm/test.jpg``` to store pictures in RAM. Reboot will delete them.

Comment: @JosephPalermo I can only think of one - you can control the maximum size of your partition

Answer (score 0):

You can call raspistill using Python if you want. Here is an example that runs the raspistill command repeatedly with a second delay:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess

dir = "/home/pi/Desktop/cam_images/"

while (True):
    fileName= "img_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + ".jpg"
    cmd = "raspistill -o " + dir + fileName
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)   
    sleep(1)
```